# Select column's occurence order without group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have two tables, users and coupons

| id | first_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Roberta |
| 2 | Oliver |
| 3 | Shayna |
| 4 | Fechin |

| id | discount | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20% | 1 |
| 2 | 40% | 2 |
| 3 | 15% | 3 |
| 4 | 30% | 1 |
| 5 | 10% | 1 |
| 6 | 70% | 4 |

What I want to do is select from the coupons table until I've selected X users.

so If I chose X = 2 the resulting table would be

| id | discount | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20% | 1 |
| 2 | 40% | 2 |
| 4 | 30% | 1 |
| 5 | 10% | 1 |

I've tried using both `dense_rank` and `row_number` but they return the count of occurrences of each user_id not it's order.

```
SELECT id,
       discount,
       user_id,
       dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)
FROM coupons
```

I'm guessing I need to do it in multiple subqueries (which is fine) where the first subquery would return something like

| id | discount | user_id | order_of_occurence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20% | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 40% | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 15% | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 30% | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 10% | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | 70% | 4 | 4 |

which I can then use to filter by what I need.

PS: I'm using postgresql.

Comment: you need to add an order by to your dense_rank

Comment: I think you want `order by id` and no `partition by` at all.

Comment: Thanks. changing `partition by user_id` to `order by user_id` seemed to have worked.
(feel free to answer so I can accept it)

Comment: Btw is this the best solution for my problem (selecting X users). I'm not sure if I'm doing an X Y problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stated that you want to parameterize the query so that you can retrieve X users. I'm reading that as all coupons for the first X distinct `user_id`s *in coupon `id` column order*.

It appears your attempt was close. `dense_rank()` is the right idea. Since you want to look over the entire table you can't use `partition by`. And a sorting column is also required to determine the ranking.

```
with data as (
    select *,
        dense_rank() over (order by id) as dr
    from coupons
)
select * from data where dr <= <X>;
```